# Optimize three tables joins in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I am building an e-library, I have written a query which scans the rows more rows probably due to poor indexing. Here is my table structure.

1. `book_categories` (cat_id, parent_id DEFAULT NULL, cat_name, parent_cat_name DEFAULT NULL)
2. `authors` (author_id, author_name, active)
3. `books` (book_id, cat_id, author_id, book_title, book_contents, book_status ENUM (published,pending,deleted) publish_date)

Here is SQL code

```
  SELECT T.author_id, 
         T.author_name, 
         C.parent_id, 
         C.cat_id, 
         C.cat_name, 
         B.book_id, 
         B.book_title, 
         B.book_contents, 
         B.publish_date 
    FROM books B, 
         authors T, 
         book_categories C 
   WHERE B.author_id = T.author_id 
     AND C.cat_id = B.cat_id 
     AND book_status = 'published' 
ORDER BY published_date DESC
```

EXPLAIN of the above query

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   SIMPLE  C   ALL     PRIMARY     NULL    NULL    NULL    449     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  B   ref     author_id,cat_id    cat_id  4   bookdb.C.cat_id     214     Using where
1   SIMPLE  T   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   bookdb.B.author_id  1
```

### Indexes & Keys

```
Alter table books 
add Foreign Key (author_id) references authors (author_id) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;

Alter table books 
add Foreign Key (cat_id) references book_categories (cat_id) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;

Create Index books_INX ON books(cat_id,book_status,published_date);
```

Comment: @Juha Syrjälä  i added them but some how they are missing. author_id is the primary key in authors table, cat_id is PK in book_categories and book_id is PK in books table

Comment: You said that this query scans too many rows? But is the query fast enough? How many rows you have in each table?

Comment: I am using LIMIT 10 with this query and it scans 650+ rows. The are more than 110K published books and 50K are not published yet. If I remove order by from this query the number of rows scan reduced to 250.

Answer (score 1):

Your indexes are fine. Don't worry about it scanning a few hundred rows (~0.5% of the table), as long as it is being done quickly. Is it quick enough?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any indexes created on those tables... if there aren't indexes don't expect MySQL to create them on "the fly" and use them. How about defining some?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: I have added indexes in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `author_id` to index `books_INX`. Try to move `published_date` to different place (first, last...) in `books_INX`. For example:

```
Create Index books_INX ON books(cat_id,author_id,book_status,published_date);
```

Make sure that `author_id` and `cat_id` are primary keys for `author` and `book_category` tables, respectively. Also `book_id` should probably be the primary key for `books` table, even if it shouldn't affect this particular query.

Comment: I did exactly you said but results are same